# Is there a way to automatically deny using sql reserved word for column name?

Tags: php, mysql

So, can it be done with specialised programs (like MySQL workbench) or do I have to write a function that checks the presence of reserved keywords in queries for naming and denies using them?

Comment: How are they being defined, by a user?  Why do you want to deny them?  Just use backticks.

Comment: The (mid) latter would apply.

Comment: If you're accepting column names from users, it may be better to whitelist acceptable names.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I mean I want to avoid using sql keywords for column names in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to automatically reject such names. Instead you can only enforce a strict usage rule by running a checker over your database in a regular interval (e.g. on commit in a version control system) and reject a script if that doesn't conform to your set of rules.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of denying you just have to properly format them. In mysql you have to use backticks around identifiers to avoid a confusion

Comment: your previous avatar was way better. `(v_o)`